# Edit attribute of object jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, append

Lets say I have the following object here :

```
var options = {
    'chart': {
        'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
        'chartArea': {
            'backgroundColor': 'transparent'
        },
        'seriesType': 'line',
        'curveType': 'function'
    }};
```

I would like to append later a new value for the index `displayRangeSelector`, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an array it's an object literal and you could add attribute to it like following :

```
options.chart['displayRangeSelector']='value';
//OR
options.chart.displayRangeSelector='value';
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var options = {
    'chart': {
        'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
        'chartArea': {
            'backgroundColor': 'transparent'
        },
        'seriesType': 'line',
        'curveType': 'function'
    }};

options.chart['displayRangeSelector']='value';
console.log(options.chart);
```

Comment: It seems I've missunderstood it as an array, Ill go ahead and edit the question, thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's an object, not an array.

You can try this:

```
options.chart['foregroundColor'] = "blue";
```

or this

```
options.chart.foregroundColor = "blue";
options.chart.chartArea.foregroundColor = "blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jquery, You can extend your object

example

```
    var options = {
        'chart': {
            'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
            'chartArea': {
                'backgroundColor': 'transparent'
            },
            'seriesType': 'line',
            'curveType': 'function'
        }};


    var newChartProperty = {    
            'displayRangeSelector':'value'
    }

    $.extend(options.chart,newChartProperty);

/*Your new object will look like 
    {
        'chart': {
            'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
            'chartArea': {
                'backgroundColor': 'transparent'
            },
            'seriesType': 'line',
            'curveType': 'function',
            'displayRangeSelector':'value'
        }};
*/
```